# Android Broadcast receiver doesn't work after a period of time

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I am creating a reminder notification. I use an AlarmService class (where I create the notifications) and an AlarmReceiver class that extends a BroadcastReceiver. The notification are correctly created but I receive the notification only for those reminder within a certain period of times. For example if I set the reminder after 30 minutes the notification doesn't work. In my service class I return START_STICKY. This is my code:

```
public class AlarmService extends Service{
....
while(...){
//call to the method to create notifications
createNotification(year, month, day_of_month, hour_of_day, minute, second, reminderID);
}
return START_STICKY;
}

//method to create notifications
public void createNotification(int year, int month, int day_of_month, int hour_of_day, int 

minute, int second, int reminderID){
        counter++;

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();       
        // add minutes to the calendar object
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,month);  // the month starts with JAN == 0
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,year);    
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,day_of_month);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hour_of_day);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minute);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,second);

        Intent alarmintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
        .......

        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), HELLO_ID+counter, alarmintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);

    }
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static int NOTIFICATION_ID = 555;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
         ........        

         NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                    context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.android100)
                    .setContentTitle(note)
                    .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
                    .setContentText(title)
                    .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));


            Intent notifyIntent =  new Intent(context, DisplayReminder.class);
            notifyIntent.putExtra("reminderID", ""+reminderID);


            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, reminderID, notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID++, mBuilder.build());


    }.....
```

Finally, I launch the service form an Activity (not the main activity) in this way:

```
Intent alarmServiceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmService.class);
startService(alarmServiceIntent);
```

And this is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.papp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/android100"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppHoloTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="Le tue medicine" 
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:label="Inserisci un nuovo promemoria"
            android:name=".InsertNewReminder">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:label="Anteprima promemoria"
            android:name=".DisplayOverview">
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver">
<!--                    <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
                    </intent-filter> -->
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".AlarmService"></service>

        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".GalleryListMainActivity">
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:label="Salvataggio promemoria"
            android:name="com.example.papp.DbActivity">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:label="Salvataggio promemoria"
            android:name=".InsertNewRemindeResponse"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:label="Promemoria"
            android:name=".DisplayReminder">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:label="Modifica promemoria"
            android:name=".UpdateReminder">
        </activity>


       <receiver android:name=".BootReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>  

          <activity
            android:label="Cancellazione promemoria"
            android:name=".DeleteReminder"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
        </activity>



    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>

</manifest>
```

I tried different attempts but with no succes: I am sure that if I kill the application manually the service restart automatically (thanks to the START_STICKY). 
Any suggestions? Thanks...

Comment: Check my question here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16954375/my-phone-doesnt-wakeup-on-alarm... May be you can get some idea.

Comment: Thansk, But I don't turn off the device. The device is on but the notifications after a certain period of time doesn't work...

Comment: I had created dfferent packages for different classes. Now I have inserted all the classes in a single package but the problem persist. The remiders within the first about 30 minutes correctly appear while over a certain period of time (e.g. 30 minute) nothing happens. Please help me

Comment: Sorry bro i am not able to help you, but i've, really, never worked on Alarms or Reminders since the question i asked, as i got busy with other projects. But still i'll try to help you by upcoming sunday. Thats for sure.

Comment: Also, I tried using IntentService instead of Service but the result is the same...